# React navigation with hooks and header function - state is not updating

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation

Trying to use react navigation with hooks and a button in the navigation header.

I can pass the handleShowModalLogin function to the navigation header and I can see the button is clicked, but the problem is the setShowLoginModal is not updating the showLoginModal state to true.  Not sure why this is not working.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import {
  Image,
  Platform,
  ScrollView,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  View,
  Button,
} from 'react-native';

import LoginModal from './users/LoginModal';

const HomeScreen = ({navigation}, props) => {

  const [showLoginModal, setShowLoginModal] = useState(false);

  const handleShowModalLogin = (value) => {
    console.log("showLoginModal button clicked: ", value)
    if(value === "on"){
      setShowLoginModal(true);
    }else{
      setShowLoginModal(false);
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('navigation handler set with showLoginModal set:', showLoginModal)
    navigation.setParams({ handleShowModalLogin: handleShowModalLogin });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("showLoginModal value changed: ", showLoginModal), [showLoginModal]
  })

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>

      <LoginModal showLoginModal={showLoginModal} />

      <ScrollView
        style={styles.container}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}>

      </ScrollView>

    </View>
  );

};

HomeScreen.navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
  title: "Home",
  headerRight: (
    <View style={styles.headerComContainer}>
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.getParam('handleShowModalLogin')('on')
        }}
        title="Login"
        color="#841584"
        accessibilityLabel="Login" />
    </View>
  )
});
```

Here's the login modal component.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Text, TouchableOpacity, View, ScrollView } from "react-native";
import Modal from 'modal-enhanced-react-native-web';

export default function LoginModal(props){

  const [visibleModal, setModalVisible] = useState(props.showLoginModal);

  return (
    <View>

      <Modal
        isVisible={visibleModal}
        onBackdropPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}
      >
        <View>
          <Text>Hello!</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setModalVisible(false)}>
            <View>
              <Text>Close</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal>

    </View>
  );

}
```

Comment: When you say it's not updating, do you mean the console.log statement on the 3rd line of handleShowModalLogin shows the old value? Or do you mean that the component doesn't rerender?

Comment: Yes, it shows the old value and the component does not render.

Comment: That second `console.log` in your handler doesn't do what you expect it to. Your handler function closes over `showModalLogin`, and you then use `useEffect` to make sure that your nav params are only set once, so whenever you do `navigation.getParam('handleShowModalLogin')()` it will always log the initial value (false) rather than the current value. That doesn't explains why it doesn't re-render though.

Comment: Well, react re-renders when state or props update (mostly). Drop a `useEffect(() => console.log(showLoginModal), [showLoginModal]);` in your `HomeScreen` component, it'll log any time `showLoginModal` updates value, or completely omit the array and it'll log on every render.  If the re-render isn't happening where/when you expect it to, then back track the call stack until you see it updating as expected and see why those changes aren't propagating to your component.

Comment: @DrewReese I tried that (code snippet updated), console looks fine, but the component is not re-rendering. 1) navigation handler set with showLoginModal set: false
2) showLoginModal value changed:  false
3) showLoginModal button clicked:  on
4) showLoginModal value changed:  true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [visibleModal, setModalVisible] = useState(props.showLoginModal);
```

This code in the LoginModal creates a state, who's initial **initial** value is props.showLoginModal. After that initial value though, there's no connection with the prop. Changing the prop later will not cause the state to change.

You seem to be trying to mix having LoginModal be a controlled component (where a parent handles the logic, and then controls it through props) and an uncontrolled component (where the component manages its own state). Instead, i'd recommend picking one or the other.

From the fact that you're trying to control it externally, it looks like you want to create a controlled component. So your login modal will need modification to have additional props to notify the parent of the clicks. Perhaps an "onBackdropPressed" and an "onClosePressed", as in:

```
export default function LoginModal(props){
  return (
    <View>
      <Modal
        isVisible={props.showLoginModal}
        onBackdropPress={() => props.onBackdropPressed()}
      >
        <View>
          <Text>Hello!</Text>
          <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => props.onClosePressed()>
            <View>
              <Text>Close</Text>
            </View>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </Modal>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Don't forget to modify the home screen to pass those additional props in, as in:

```
<LoginModal 
  showLoginModal={showLoginModal} 
  onBackdropPressed={() => setShowLoginModal(false)}
  onClosePressed={() => setShowLoginModal(false)}
/>
```